# What do these numbers mean?

Tags: support, reputation

[image: screenshot]

And why does a click do nothing, despite that the mouse cursor is a finger?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work

Comment: Are you sure this is a discussion, and not a suport question?

Comment: Perhaps the cursor should not turn to a **pointer**.

Comment: THE NUMBERS, MASON! WHAT DO THEY MEAN?

Answer (score 7):

The numbers show how much reputation you earned or lost on that question today,

(+10 for each upvote on your answer)
+5 for each upvote on your question
-2 for each downvote on your post
(-1 for each answer you downvote)

Obviously, it's a question, because you have 4 events there, 2 up and 2 down.
If you want to see the break-down, click on the triangle.
If you want to go to the question, perhaps to investigate why you got the downvotes and what you might improve, click on its title.

There's not really a good reason for showing the hand on the full line, AFAICT.

Answer (score 2):

The answer Deduplicator gave is perfectly OK.

As for the `pointer` cursor, here is the explanation:

The problem around the pointer is that The table-row `<tr>` has the class `expandable-row` which actually sets the cursor to **pointer**. But only the post body is **actually expandable**. Therefore, clicking on the row does not work. You need to click on the post body (or the arrow to the left of it).

This is a minor UI bug I'd say. Should I retag this question as a "BUG" or can that be done elsewhere?